# PHP error handling has disappeared since upgrading to mountain lion

Tags: php, error-handling, xampp, osx-mountain-lion

I recently installed mountain lion, and when I went to start apache from XAMPP I got an error requesting I disabling web sharing in order for XAMPP to work. After some research I found a command which would turn of the apache that comes bundled with mountain lion. This worked and apache from XAMPP started.

However the next thing I have noticed is im no longer getting error handling.

Im using fuelphp, however instead of an error message when there are issues with my code I get a blank page with the words NO DATA RECEIVED :S.

For example removing a `;` from the end of line, results in the above opposed to a readble error message.

I checked the frameworks index.php file which has error reporitng on

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Could any one give me a step by step explanation of how to get my error reporting back :'(

Comment: You may want to make the changes in php.ini instead.

Comment: how do I find the php.ini in my XAMP setup, I have never had to make changes to it before :(

Comment: I found it but it says: display_errors = On

Comment: does `phpinfo()` in your "broke it on purpose" script show errors to be off? php settings can be overridden in all kinds of places. what counts is what php says is in effect at the spot in question, which phpinfo will report on.

Comment: It shows display errors as on and error_reporting as 30719

Comment: @Ben_hawk In case you're running Chrome, test it with another browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on Max OS X too. It's definitely a server configuration issue as exactly the same code works perfectly well on Windows and multiple Linux environments.

My Apache/PHP was installed on the Mac through XAMPP. Others who are suffering from the same issue, please let me know in the comments if you too are using XAMPP. I want to track down the exact server config that is causing this problem.

For now, I have a hacky workaround:

In **fuel/core/bootstrap.php**, add this to the top of your `register_shutdown_function`

```
$last_error = error_get_last();
if (is_array($last_error) && \Fuel::$env == \Fuel::DEVELOPMENT && in_array($last_error['type'], array(4, 1, 256, 64))) {
    exit();
}
```

Weird thing is though, it's hit and miss as to whether it catches the error. So I sometimes have to refresh a few times.

Oh and you must set the environment to DEVELOPMENT. This is to stop leaking errors in production deployed sites.

**EDIT:**: It seems that MAMP (latest version 2.1.2 at time of writing) does not suffer from this issue. Neither does XAMPP 1.8.1-beta1. So you could also try using those.